# How can I merge a result set from a matrix table?

Tags: sql

Say I have a price matrix that looks like this:

```
ID  SalePrice   CostPrice
1   200         0
1   0           75
1   0           100
2   150         0
2   0           50
2   500         0
```

I then have a table with 75k ID´s that I wish to join with the price matrix and return one row per ID with the lowest value for SalePrice and CostPrice. Like so:

```
ID  SalePrice   CostPrice
200             75
150             50
```

Here is the sql I currently use:

```
declare @priceMatrix TABLE(
prodNo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
salePrice decimal,
costPrice decimal)

INSERT INTO @priceMatrix
SELECT pm.ID, pm.SalePr, pm.CstPr 
FROM PriceMatrix pm
GROUP BY pm.ID, pm.SalePrice, pm.CostPrice
ORDER BY pm.ID ASC 

SELECT ProductTable.ProdNo,
(SELECT TOP 1 salePrice FROM @priceMatrix WHERE ProductTable.ID = ID AND 
costPrice = 0 ORDER BY salePrice ASC) AS SalePrice , 

(SELECT TOP 1 costPrice FROM @priceMatrix WHERE ProductTable.ID = ID AND 
salePrice = 0 ORDER BY costPrice ASC) AS CostPrice , 

FROM ProductTable

GROUP BY ProductTable.ID
```

But with 75000 ID´s the performance is just terrible using sub queries. Not to say completely useless.

Is there an effective way to achieve what I´m looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductTable.ProdNo,
       sub1.MIN_SALE_PRICE as SalePrice , 
       sub2.MIN_COST_PRICE as CostPrice
FROM ProductTable pt
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(salePrice) MIN_SALE_PRICE, ID
               FROM @priceMatrix
               WHERE costPrice = 0 
               GROUP BY ID) sub1 ON pt.ID=sub1.ID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(costPrice ) MIN_COST_PRICE, ID
               WHERE salePrice = 0 
               FROM @priceMatrix
               GROUP BY ID) sub2 ON pt.ID=sub2.ID
GROUP BY ProductTable.ID
```

Move the sub selects with ORDER BY to JOINS to evaluate them once for all products

Comment: That was it! @StanislavL

Answer (score 0):

This actually turned out to execute faster by 1 sek:

```
SELECT ProductTable.ProdNo,

(SELECT MIN(salePrice)
           FROM PriceMatrix
           WHERE PriceMatrix.ID = ProductTable.ID 
           AND PriceMatrix.CostPrice = 0 
           AND PriceMatrix.SalePrice > 0) AS SalePrice,

(SELECT MIN(costPrice)
           FROM PriceMatrix
           WHERE PriceMatrix.ID = ProductTable.ID 
           AND PriceMatrix.CostPrice > 0 
           AND PriceMatrix.SalePrice = 0) AS CostPrice

FROM ProductTable
```